# How to fix `405 Not Allowed` error with coveralls

Tags: node.js, node-modules, code-coverage, coveralls

I've been getting my code coverage with the following command and it's been working fine:

```
nyc report --reporter=lcov && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls
```

All of a sudden I'm getting get a `405` error with the error below:

**Error received:**

> ```
> > nyc report --reporter=lcov && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls
>
> /User/tobie/Desktop/node/ballers-api/node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js:19
>     throw err;
>     ^
> Bad response: 405 <html>
> <head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
> <body>
> <center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx</center>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

PS: No, I haven't made any changes to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encountered the same on GitHub actions. By checking https://coveralls.io where the coverage is uploaded to it says they are down for maintenance. Guess there is nothing else which can be done for resolving this error than wait until they are finished and resend afterwards again.